# add apache2 DirectoryIndex outside virtual host

Tags: apache2

I have several virtualhost websites on my server and want to make Apache load a set file if no index file exists. I tried

```
DirectoryIndex /index.php
```

but that only loads the index at the root of the virtualhost.
next I tried

```
DirectoryIndex /var/www/index.php
```

but that came back with error 404. So I then tried

```
DirectoryIndex /../index.php
```

but that came back with error 400 as well. All of the results in Google are about how to disable the default index, not replace it.

my file tree is

```
www > index.php (file I wish to load if no index)
      virtualhostsite1 > pages
                         subdirectories
                         etc.
      virtualhostsite2 > pages
                         subdirectories
                         etc.
      virtualhostsite3 > pages
                         subdirectories
                         etc.
```

In short, I want to replace [this screen](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_rhuioznu6Us/TBmeWAr_G2I/AAAAAAAAAFE/tKCclPXdq2M/s1600/apache.png) with a custom index stored outside the Apache root elsewhere on the hard drive. I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Apache HTTPd documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex), you just use

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```

This will use the file `index.php` as directory index inside each directory.

You can also give a list of files to try. So in case no `index.html` is present, `index.php` shall be used (if present).

```
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
```

The documentation says:

> Local-url is the (%-encoded) URL of a document on the server relative to the requested directory; it is usually the name of a file in the directory.

So I guess you were quite close. Try:

```
DirectoryIndex ../index.php
```

Comment: i want to replace this page: http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_rhuioznu6Us/TBmeWAr_G2I/AAAAAAAAAFE/tKCclPXdq2M/s1600/apache.png with a custom one

Comment: This is Apache 1 and not Apache 2. Maybe consider updating?

Comment: i am using apache2

Comment: that was a pic from google of the screen

Comment: @kaioker2: Does using a real relative URI work? - I updated the answer. And if you still get a 4xx error, can you please check your Apache log file for what Apache complains about?

Comment: unfortunately no. it only works if i am in a sub folder one folder belowthe file root